# how to build a hierarchy in a cube?

Tags: ssas, cube

I have built a cube is SSAS.
Now i need to create date hierarchy.
Please suggest the steps or ways to build the hierarchies.
is a attribute and hierarchy are one and the same? which one is the first step?

Comment: http://blog.tangotechnologygroup.com/2011/01/19/creating-a-time-dimension/

Answer (score 1):

SSAS has two types of hierarchies:

- "Attribute hierarchies", normally consisting of the "All" member and all the members loaded from the source data, and
- "User hierarchies" which normally contain the "All" member and several levels below that which originate from attributes.

I omit some special cases like parent-child hierarchies here for brevity.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174760.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174935.aspx for details.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating and deploying a cube, I think it's important to understand the common methods for a proper cube design.
[In this link](http://www.nenit.net/articles/sql-server/ssas/schemas.aspx) you can find a great and simple elaboration of the two main methods of cube dimension design, the second one is the best method for a cube:

1. **Star Schema** - the fact table (usually a data-source view) contains foreign keys that reference the keys of your dimensions, which are also tables or views; A diagram of the cube visualizes a star-like shape, where the center is the facts table and the 'legs' are the dimension tables;
2. **Snowflake Schema** - pretty similar to the star schema, only now it features a deeper dimension hierarchy (e.g. Products -> Product Lines, e.g. Cities -> States -> Countries -> Continents); "Product" is a table that references the Product Lines table;

The time dimension is usually formed by a table in you database. This table can have as many date-parts as you wish to have in your cube for the sake of time drill-down.

A time dimension formed this way usually has parent-child relationships between its members, as it is a flat table in most cases. See below:

[image: Time dimension example]

That data structure allows SSAS to help you build a time dimension quite intuitively.

When creating the time dimension with the BI Development Studio wizard, you have the option of choosing "time dimension" as the dimension type.

A time dimension is not too different from any other type of dimension, only in the above example the time table references itself.

Imaging you have a product tree that references itself, meaning one table forms the whole hierarchy of the product dimension. This scenario begs for a parent-child relationship.